# Yii2: show init text for kartik/select2 on load

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-basic-app

I am using [**`KARTIK-Select2-AJAX`**](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-ajax).

All work fine, but I got id of title which I found instead text of title.[image]

How I can get title in $_POST after save? after selected item of dropdown I save this in db through other ajax request. I think that the problem lies below.

```
   'ajax' => [
        'url' => $url,
        'dataType' => 'json',
        'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) {return{q:params.term}; }')
    ],

    'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),

    'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(city) { return city.text; }'),

    'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (city) { return city.text; }'),
```

Comment: you need to show the code for the `$url` action used, to know what response is generated and how.

Comment: code of controller and $url same like in kartik demo and I got searching result, like item1, item2...
but after save I don't get text. Instead this I got id of item1 or item2 for example, like in picture above.

Comment: Ok so you mean after saving when you try to edit at that time when page loads it shows the id instead of the text of the selected `city`, and the input for which you are using the `select2` its name is `city` am i correct ?

Comment: I updated the answer hope it helps out.

Comment: hey @Anton do select the answer if it helped you solve the problem

Comment: Thank you very much! Second answer was correct and help solve the problem.

Comment: you are welcome, do select the answer as correct so others looking for the same solution would also benefit thanks in advance  @Anton

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `dropdown` for the `cities` as seeing from one of your options used, so i will use the name `city_id` in the model reference in the example.

You need to use the `initValueText` option to show the saved values `text` instead of `id`.

Just before you start your `Select2` you should add the following statement either on top of your view, or add it in the `controller/action` and pass the value to the view. I will demonstrate by adding on top of the view.

```
// Get the initial city description
$cityName = $model->city_id == '' ? '' : City::findOne($model->city_id)->name;
```

in the above line you can use the `relation` too instead of `City::findOne($model->city_id)->name` like `$model->city->name` if defined inside your model with the name `city`.

Then add the option `initValueText` to your `Select2` options.

```
'initValueText'=>$cityName
'ajax' => [
        'url' => $url,
        'dataType' => 'json',
        'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) {return{q:params.term}; }')
    ],
'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(city) { return city.text; }'),
'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (city) { return city.text; }'),
```

**EDIT**

You want the options to include text only and not `id`, mens the `<option value="City Name">City Name</option>` and for that you have to update the response from the `url` as i asked you earlier in my first comment, under your question ,you have to add the exact code to get exact update.

I assume that the `$url` that you used in the `ajax` option will hit and action name `/citysearch`, and the model name is `City` in which you have to search for the cities, update the following action code accordingly.I have tested it and works correctly.

```
public function actionCitysearch($q = null, $id = null) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];

        if (!is_null($q)) {
            $data = City::find()
                    ->select(new \yii\db\Expression('[[name]] as id,[[name]] as text'))
                    ->where(['like', 'name', $q])
                    ->limit(20)
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all();
            $out['results'] = array_values($data);
        } elseif ($id > 0) {
            $city=City::find($id);
            $out['results'] = ['id' => $city->name, 'text' => $city->name];
        }
        return $out;
}
```

Comment: I apologize for not fast feedback;)
Yes, it work to this basic situation, but I mean, how to make so that in $_POST it was passed  pair like ['text1'=>'text1'] and not like in basic example ['1'=>'text1']. Is not problem get this value of text like you had write), but in some case may need get 
<option val='text'>text</option> 
instead 
<option value='1'>text</option>
may it possible do on js, but I'm not found even basic documentation, how it can extend or override...

Comment: yes! that's what you wanted. please can you select the answer. @Anton

Comment: I assume that you say me what would I select what might stay here and what delete.
All what wrote below "EDIT" is correct and approached me.

Comment: the originally answered text should not be deleted as it is the part of the answer that was initially assumed, and missing part has been added as the **`EDIT`** and mentioned so its understood that in your specific case the **EDIT** part works and if someone does not want the `name=>value` pair both as text they can use the first part of the answer which is logically not wrong by any means and can still help others too. So its ok to mark it as correct answer :) have a good day ahead @Anton See [**`HERE`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)